# Scala: Convert columns into rows based on index 0 value?

Tags: dataframe, scala

I have a dataframe that contains the name of the item and then all the prices that item was sold for - I want to turn them all into separate rows.

df looks like this:

| Name |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 1.0 | 1.5 | 1.2 | 1.3 | 1.8 |
| apple | 1.5 | 1.4 | 1.3 |  |  |
| pear | 0.8 | 0.9 | 1.0 | 0.8 |  |

expected output:

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| orange | 1.0 |
| orange | 1.5 |
| orange | 1.2 |
| orange | 1.3 |
| orange | 1.8 |
| apple | 1.5 |
| apple | 1.4 |
| apple | 1.3 |
| pear | 0.8 |
| pear | 0.9 |
| pear | 1.0 |
| pear | 0.8 |

I have tried using pivot(), groupBy() and explode() but nothing's working :(

Comment: @RaymondKwok OP has specified Scala and Spark; not python and pandas.

Comment: @bella I think you want to [do a pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809646/spark-rows-to-columns-like-transpose-or-pivot). To further help can you provide any code you currently have?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars='Name').sort_values(by=['Name'])
```

Comment: try to add names to columns and execute the code above. Then, you can use `drop(columns='variable',).dropna()`

Comment: This looks like python code, OP has specified scala; this code won't interoperate.